# Chart.JS Underfined with JSON

Tags: json, chart.js

Hello guys i got a problem, i cant display my graph it will become like this
[image]

As u can see there i also print console log.Nothing error occur.
Below is my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Line</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="chart-container">
<canvas id="line-chartcanvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="js/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/chartmain.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My chartmain.js

```
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost/Media/chart.php",
    type: "GET",
    success : function (data) {

      var count = [];
      var displayLink = [];

      for(var i in data){
        count.push ("Player" + data[i].count);
        displayLink.push(data[i].displayLink);

      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: displayLink,
        datasets : [
          {
            data: displayLink,
            label : 'Score',
            backgroundColor: 
            "#F1c40F"
          }
                ]

    };
     var ctx =$("#line-chartcanvas");
     var barGraph = new Chart(ctx,{
      type: 'bar',
      data: chartdata

    });
    console.log(data);
    },

    error : function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
});
```

My Json Array

```
[
  {
    "count": "3",
    "displayLink": "www.bharian.com.my"
  },
  {
    "count": "1",
    "displayLink": "www.hmetro.com.my"
  },
  {
    "count": "6",
    "displayLink": "www.nst.com.my"
  },
  {
    "count": "1",
    "displayLink": "www.sinarharian.com.my"
  },
  {
    "count": "1",
    "displayLink": "www.utusan.com.my"
  }
]
```

I think perhaps it cant read my data from JSON but in console log it read

Comment: Seems ok , can you please post chart.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me, already found the answer, I cant get data from JSON but i can data from MySQL